# Ajuda com Array

Tags: javascript, html, array

Ola pessoal Estou com um problema com javascript.
Possuo um array com 500 posições, quero imprimir todos os dados no meu
html. Porem quando eu jogo esses dados dentro de uma div ele puxa apenas o ultimo elemento.
Fico grato pela ajuda.
Segue código.

```
<button getList> campos</button>
<textarea id="conteudo"></textarea>



app.getList("FieldList", function(reply){
            var Campos = reply.qFieldList.qItems;
            var texto = document.getElementById('conteudo')

            Campos.forEach((element,index) => {
                texto.innerHTML = element.qName + index

                console.log(element.qName,index)
            })
```

Comment: Coloca um **+** depois do innerHTML assim:  `+=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que puxe todos os elementos, é só você colocar um + depois do innerHTML, para que ele adicione todos os elementos do array. O código fica dessa forma:

```
<button getList> campos</button>
<textarea id="conteudo"></textarea>

app.getList("FieldList", function(reply){
            var Campos = reply.qFieldList.qItems;
            var texto = document.getElementById('conteudo')

            Campos.forEach((element,index) => {
                texto.innerHTML += element.qName + index

                console.log(element.qName,index)
            })
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado